# What are upstream/downstream flows in the Kotlin language

Tags: terminology

In the [flow documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/flow.md#intermediate-flow-operators) they mentioned an upstream and a downstream flows:

> Flows can be transformed with operators, just as you would with collections and sequences. Intermediate operators are applied to an upstream flow and return a downstream flow.

Given code (from the same source):

```
 (1..3).asFlow() // a flow of requests
        .map { request -> performRequest(request) }
        .collect { response -> println(response) }
```

Do upstream and downstream mean an input and an output (a return value)? For example when the programming language starts to execute the `.map` part, a value of `(1..3).asFlow()` is an upstream flow and a return value of the `.map {...}` is a downstream flow?

Comment: Yes, and also yes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank you. Can you reformulate it as SE answer so I can mark you as accepted?

Comment: cross-site duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76773712/what-are-upstream-downstream-flows-in-the-kotlin-language

Answer (score 2):

Data flows can be categorized in two directions: upstream and downstream.

**1) Upstream Flow**: The upstream flow refers to the source of data or events. It is where the data originates or is produced. In a data flow pipeline, the upstream is the beginning of the chain. It emits data/events that can be consumed by downstream operators or consumers. For example, in Kotlin Flow, an upstream flow could be a flow that emits data from a remote server, a database, or any other asynchronous data source.

**2) Downstream Flow**: The downstream flow refers to the consumers or operators that receive and process the data/events emitted by the upstream. Downstream operators can transform, filter, aggregate, or perform any other operation on the data as it passes through the flow. Eventually, the data reaches the final consumer or subscriber that takes the end action. In Kotlin Flow, the downstream could be the **collect** function or other operators like **map**, **filter**, etc., that process the emitted data.

In summary, the "upstream flow" is the source of data or events in a data stream, and the "downstream flow" is where the data is consumed and processed.

**Kotlin's oficial definition:**

`interface Flow<out T>`

An asynchronous data stream that sequentially emits values and completes normally or with an exception.

**Intermediate operators** on the flow such as **map, filter, take, zip**, etc are **functions** that are applied to the **upstream flow or flows** and **return a downstream flow** where further operators can be applied to. Intermediate operations do not execute any code in the flow and are not suspending functions themselves. They only set up a chain of operations for future execution and quickly return. This is known as a cold flow property.

**Terminal operators** on the flow are either suspending functions such as **collect, single, reduce, toList**, etc. or launchIn operator that starts collection of the flow in the given scope. They are applied to the upstream flow and trigger execution of all operations. Execution of the flow is also called collecting the flow and is always performed in a suspending manner without actual blocking. Terminal operators complete normally or exceptionally depending on successful or failed execution of all the flow operations in the upstream. The most basic terminal operator is collect, for example:

```
try {
    flow.collect { value ->
        println("Received $value")
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    println("The flow has thrown an exception: $e")
}
```